# Why is this auto complete function not auto-completing in Linux?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, autocomplete

In my bashrc. I am trying to bash complete the command `scp` as follows

```
function _scp_complete
{
  COMPREPLY=""
  COMPREPLY+=( $(cat ~/.ssh_complete ) )
  COMPREPLY+=( $( find . ! -name . -prune -type f ) )
}
complete -F _scp_complete scp
```

The idea is that when pressing `scp [tab]` I see all files in the current directory and the words listed in the text file `~/.ssh_complete`. Let's assume this file contain the following entries:

alex@192.0.0.1
alex@192.0.0.2

The desired behavior is as follows: I type `scp alex@[TAB]` and tab completion'completes' the command to scp alex@192.0.0. automatically, because there are only two possible arguments starting with alex@ (assuming there is no similar named file in the currect working directory.):

```
>scp alex@[TAB]
  alex@192.0.0.1 alex@192.0.0.1 
>scp alex@192.0.0.
```

The behavior I get with the described implementation is as follows: I type `scp alex@[TAB]` and the tab completion does *not* complete anything, but lists every possible argument below the command:

```
>scp alex@[TAB]
  alex@192.0.0.1 alex@192.0.0.1 file1 Music Pictures ./.emacs <ALL files in the current directory>
>scp alex@
```

How can I fix the function to get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `COMP_WORDS` array to get the current word that has been typed. Then use the `compgen` command to generate possible completions based on your original word list.

Try the following:

```
_scp_complete()
{
  local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
  COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$(< ~/.ssh_complete) $( find . ! -name . -prune -type f )" -- $cur) )
}
complete -F _scp_complete scp
```

Take a look at this blog post for more details: [Writing your own Bash Completion Function](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/writing-your-own-bash-completion.html)

Note, I don't think this completion will work on files with spaces in their names.

Also note that instead of `$(cat file)`, it's more efficient to use `$(< file)` to extract the text from a file.